# Remove YoastSEO meta description from output/source

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I want to have a drop down for my client to choose a particular set of meta descriptions, I can get that meta description to appear but I can't seem to find a way to get the existing YoastSEO meta description to disappear.

I've checked in YoastSEO back-end and coded it so it removed the box from the back-end but no option to remove it from the output/source. I only want it removing for a particular custom post type.

Any got ideas or solutions they've come across before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, if anyone has problems in the future.

```
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_desc', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: That will remove the `og:description` tag, not the regular description tag. You'll also need to filter `wpseo_metadesc`.